# How to handle onChange events from another classes' component?

Tags: reactjs

As a react newbie, I'm having trouble getting an event to fire from the `<RadioGroup />` component. I'm not sure how or where to handle the events. Please help me find a good solution. I guess this is a really vanilla sample for an expert. Thank  you kindly. Most of the code here is not actual problem, only a bird's eye view of what I'm working  with. Thanks again.

I have a few classes like so...

```
export default class Wellness extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
    <Statement 1... text={_text} id={_id} /> // for example
    <Statement 2... />
  }
}

class Statement extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div id={'statement'+this.props.id}>
        <p>{ this.props.text }</p>
        <RadioGroup id={this.props.id} />
      </div>
    )
  }

}

class RadioGroup extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div id={`group-${this.props.id}`}>
        <input type="radio" value={0}
          checked={this.state.checked === 0} />
        <label>0</label>
        <input type="radio" value={1}
          checked={this.state.checked === 1}/>
        <label>1</label>
        <input type="radio" value={2}
          checked={this.state.checked === 2}/>
        <label>2</label>
        <input type="radio" value={3}
          checked={this.state.checked === 3} />
        <label>3</label>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by maintaining child component's state in parent and passing a function as a prop to child component to detect any changes.

So in your case, `Wellness` component will keep the state of all the `Statement` component and will pass a function (`handleStatement1RadioChange`) as a prop (`onRadioClick`) and its state (e.g. `statement1Checked`)  to it so that it can know of any changes.

This is how it will look.

```
class Wellness extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      statement1Checked: 0
    };
  }

  handleStatement1RadioChange = checked => {
    this.setState({
      statement1Checked: checked
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Statements
        text="Statement 1"
        id={1234}
        currentChecked={this.state.statement1Checked}
        onRadioClick={this.handleStatement1RadioChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Now that `Statement` component has received the required props it will apply the same strategy and will pass the same props to `RadioGroup` component.

```
// Functional Component
const Statements = props => {
  const handleRadioGroupChange = checked => {
    props.onRadioClick(checked);
  };

  return (
    <div id={"statement" + props.id}>
      <p>{props.text}</p>
      <RadioGroup
        id={props.id}
        checkedRadio={props.currentChecked}
        onRadioChange={handleRadioGroupChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

`RadioGroup` component will call the function passed to it (`handleRadioGroupChange`). This will call the function (`onRadioClick`) that was passed by `Wellness` component.

Now the `RadioButton` component will take those props and handle its working by implementing `onChange` on `input` and setting the `checked` value that was passed as prop (`checkedRadio`).

```
const RadioGroup = props => {
  const handleRadioChange = e => {
    const currentChecked = parseInt(e.target.value);
    props.onRadioChange(currentChecked);
  };
  return (
    <div id={`group-${props.id}`}>
      <input
        type="radio"
        value={0}
        checked={props.checkedRadio === 0}
        onChange={handleRadioChange}
      />
      <label>0</label>
      <input
        type="radio"
        value={1}
        checked={props.checkedRadio === 1}
        onChange={handleRadioChange}
      />
      <label>1</label>
      <input
        type="radio"
        value={2}
        checked={props.checkedRadio === 2}
        onChange={handleRadioChange}
      />
      <label>2</label>
      <input
        type="radio"
        value={3}
        checked={props.checkedRadio === 3}
        onChange={handleRadioChange}
      />
      <label>3</label>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is the working example on [Code Sandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/5v7mjnkx1l)

Answer (score 1):

The normal approach in React would be to pass a function (as a prop) to the `RadioGroup` component. In the `RadioGroup` component, you can call this function in this way:

`onChange={e => this.props.handleRadioChange(e, id)}`

You can really pass any number of parameters to the `handleRadioChange` function that you define in the Parent component. Be sure to note that if you follow this way, you will have initialize the state via props from the parent.

Let me know if this is of help.

Comment: I'm confused where to put that. I have `Wellness` class that uses `Statement` and `RadioGroup`. Can you diagram an example, a simple one, in this structure, or can you recommend a better structure? Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at this one - https://codesandbox.io/s/0xw40m628p
I am passing in the questions array as a prop. You can pass in the props similarly. You would need another prop, for example, the function that goes into the RadioGroup component as the handler. In the RadioGroup component, you can simply attach `onChange={(e => this.props.handleRadioChange(e, index)}`. This will call your parent component function.

Comment: @tidelake Please do accept the answer if you find it useful.